# 3D clickable pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

Could anyone here recommend me some JS/jQuery charting library with which I can make a 3D clickable pie chart? For example: I have two charts on page. If I click on slice called "animals" in the first chart, the second chart will display more detail info about animals... Im using Open Flash Chart right now, but there is no 3D pie chart and there is a problem when user doesn´t have a Flash also. That´s why I want JS/jQuery solution...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) Try Google-ing it first. Heck, even Google has it's own [chart library](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

Comment: Thanks, before I ask anything, I do some googling ;) I checked this library too and it doesn´t seem that it can be set to 3D ;) I didn´t find any suitable solution for me. That´s why Im asking here ;)

Comment: How to make a bad chart worse? Take a pie chart and make it 3D. There are ALWAYS better ways to visualise data than with 3D pie charts. A pie chart is rarely the best choice for a chart, with very few exceptions. A 3D pie chart is never, ever a good choice.

Comment: Don´t tell me that, I´m just following my boss´s wishes :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a simple solution if you want the pie chart to be actual 3d. If you really need it to be 3d I'd look into Three.js but it's kinda complicated, especially if you want the chart to be clickable.

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/

Otherwise there's plenty of graph generators out there. I wrote one myself that uses normal html elements (except for the pie charts :/ ) so you can easily attach mouse events to them.

http://www.zhereicome.com/experiments/statics/statisquares/

Comment: Thanks...IMHO it doesn´t need to be 3D, but my boss is constantly asking for unnecessary crap like this, which takes me a much more of searching, thinking and coding than application itself... :/

Comment: http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/3d-pie/

http://codecanyon.net/item/3d-pie-chart-with-javascript/full_screen_preview/2450676